# Math.Abs for difference of two ulong (unsigned long) values

Tags: c#, .net, math

I am looking for Math.Abs(ulong,ulong) with return type ulong.
But it seems Microsoft only implemented it for long, int and so on.
Is there another fast way to do it?

Sorry, need to correct:

```
Math.Abs(ulong - ulong)
```

So it can get negative, and be out of the range of a long.

Comment: The absolute value of any positive number will be the same number.  e.g. there are *no* Math.Abs methods for any unsigned values.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unsigned long values are always positive, as they do not contain a sign.  As such, `Math.Abs` would make no sense for `ulong`.

---

Given your new question, you can use:

```
ulong difference = first > second ? first-second : second-first;
```

This will give you the difference between the two values, which is effectively the absolute value of the result you'd get by subtracting the two values as if they were signed.

Comment: Lol .. that point went completely over my head :D  So obvious now you mention it ;)

Comment: Sorry. Yes, you are absolutely right, I corrected my question.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid going out of range I think you want something like this:

```
a > b ? a-b : b-a
```